# The Viewbox control and drag drop

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, viewbox

When using the XAML Viewbox control on win8 rt, for different screen sizes (resolutions) where the control automatically scales the

e.Delta.Translation drifts from the correct X,Y position. The further you drag the control in Drag Drop manipulations the further the position drifts.

**XAML**

```
<Viewbox x:Name="viewbox" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform"  >
  <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" Width="1366" Height="768">
    <Image x:Name="test" ManipulationDelta="test_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All" ></Image>
     </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

**C#**

```
void test_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e) {
      var dragableItem = sender as Image;
      var translateTransform = dragableItem.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
      translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
      translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y; 

    }
```

Any ideas how to get an accurate position / fix for this ?